# How can I identify quotient set $\mathcal{V}\backslash\{0\}_{/\sim}$ as geometrically object?

Tags: geometry, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let $\mathcal{V}=\{\overrightarrow{AB}\;| A, B \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$. On $\mathcal{V} \backslash\{0\}$ define following equivalence relation: $v\sim w \iff \exists\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{*}$ such that $v=\lambda w$.
How can I identify quotient set $\mathcal{V}\backslash\{0\}_{/\sim}$ as geometrically object?

Comment: What is $0 \in \mathcal V$ and how do you multiply $\overrightarrow{AB}$ with a real number? Do you perhaps mean $\mathcal V = \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @PaulFrost $\mathcal{V}$ is practically the set of all vectors from plane, and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: And $0 \in \mathcal{V}$ is the null vector

Comment: And what precisely is $\overrightarrow{AB}$? You should define it. Frankly, your definition of $\mathcal V$ is unclear and does not allow to introduce the structure of a vector space. You should omit it and consider $\sim$ on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is the vector that have coordinates $(x_B - x_A, y_B - y_A)$

Comment: This is called the projective space